# Construct Derived Class in Base Class' Constructor in C++

Tags: c++, oop, polymorphism

Suppose I have a class derived from a base class.  Polymorphism allows me to call the derived class' functions through a pointer to the base class (using virtual functions).  In other words, I can have a member of the derived class "pretending" to be a member of the base class.  Keeping that in mind, is it possible for the base class, in its constructor, to actually construct a member of the derived class (which then "pretends" to be a member of the base class, so nothing breaks)?  Logically , I see no reason that this should not work, but I cannot figure out how to do it syntactically.  If this is not possible, why not?

I know that I can have a separate function that constructs a member of the derived class and returns it as a member of the base class.  That is what I will do if this ends up being impossible, but it would be cleaner to have it as a constructor (because that is what this separate function basically is).

EDIT: Here is an example of what I am looking for:

```
class base
{
  base()
  {
    this=new derived(); //This is what I am looking for
  }

  virtual func();
};

class derived : public base
{
  derived() : base()
    {}

  func()
  {
    ...
  }
};
```

As mentioned above, this could be achieved with the following:

```
base *fake_base_constructor()
{
  return new derived();
}
```

In practice, there would be multiple derived classes, and the base class constructor would choose between them based on parameters, but conceptually, you only need one.

Comment: Please add some "what I want" code. What does it mean to "pretend to be a member of the base class" (Do you also include member data?)? What does it mean to "return it as a member of the base class"?

Comment: Do you have any code, broken or otherwise, that at least *attempts* to demonstrate what you're trying to describe? And polymorphism doesn't "pretend" anything. A *cast* pretends to be something it isn't; polymorphism is behavior modification via derivation override. You can also static-polymorph via templates, but it doesn't sound like that is what you want either.

Comment: What do you mean by "nothing breaks"?  It sounds like you're talking about guaranteeing that a subclass does not break the parent's invariant (which should be maintained by all subclasses).  Is this so?

Comment: @pmr: "Pretending to be a member of the base class" was an informal way of stating that a pointer to the derived class can be cast to a pointer to the base class (it was supposed to make it less wordy).  "Returning it as a member of the base class" also meant casting it to the base class in order to return it.

Comment: @RonaldBarzell: I just meant that it could be cast into the base class, so that type-checking would pass.

Comment: `this=new derived`? [Time to read a C++ book](http://jcatki.no-ip.org/fncpp/Resources). Like, _really_ thoroughly.

Comment: you can use integers (or even better an `enum`) to denote the relevant classes, and a `switch` statement in your function.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: Yes, I know that does not work.  That is to show what I am trying to accomplish.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf: I know how to do that; I was asking if there is a way to do it directly in the constructor of the base class.

Comment: Thank you to @Cheersandhth.-Alf for the term "factory function".  Knowing that, my question can be rephrased as follows: Can the constructor of a base class act as a factory function function for its derived classes?  Sorry for the confusion I caused by not knowing that term.

Comment: @bugmenot: not directly. in theory you could let the base class have a pointer-to-derived member and let its methods forward to that derived instance. but it's just added complexity, obfuscation and inefficiency, not to mention additional ways that this could go wrong (that is, added opportunities to introduce bugs). not a good idea. forget it

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf: That is what I figured.  I was planning on using what I now know is called a factory function, but I wanted to check if there were a better way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you want to select the type of thing that you get by passing something into the constructor?  Your example gives a static selection but the text implies that there will be multiple choices.  I'm curious how you intend to use this, specifically.

Say you wanted to do something like this:

```
enum Types
{
    Type_A,
    Type_B,
};

class Base
{
public:
    Base(Types t)
    {
        switch (t)
        {
        case Type_A:
            this = <magic> A;
            break;

        case Type_B:
            this = <magic> B;
            break;
        }
    }
};
```

but the problem is that this isn't how C++ works; your object's space is already allocated by the time the constructor is hit so you can't just stuff a derived item into that space.  For instance, imagine you had this as a class member variable:

```
struct SomeStruct
{
    int i;
    Base b;
    float f;

    SomeStruct();
}

SomeStruct::SomeStruct() : i(4), b(Type_A), f(3.14f)
{
}
```

This just can't work.  It really sounds like the most straight forward solution will be for you to use a factory function; it makes it explicit that you have to deal with pointers and it's something that programmers are used to seeing:

```
Base* BaseFactory(Types t)
{
    switch (t)
    {
    case Type_A:
        return new A;

    case Type_B:
        return new B;
    }
}
```

You could do something similar with the curiously recurring template pattern but it's not as straight forward as suggested in another answer (in part because you presumably want runtime polymorphism which isn't addressed in the Wikipedia article) but it's not really necessary; regardless of your solution the code module that does the construction of these things will have to have knowledge of everything that can be created and considering that a constraint it's probably best to have that bundle of knowledge somewhere other than in the base class.  Just my opinion but I think it's safest for the long haul to avoid building big bundles of string.

Comment: This is what I was looking for; thank you.  I was forgetting about non-dynamically allocated objects!  Great explanation, and sorry again to everyone else for my lack of communication skills.

Answer (score 4):

Sounds like you want the [curiously recurring template pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern). It allows the base class to know which type is being derived from it by giving it a template parameter which is the derived type:

```
template <class D>
class Base
{ };

class Derived : public Base<Derived>
{ };
```

Now you can use the template parameter `Derived` in the definition of `Base`. For example, the constructor of `Base` could do:

```
template <class D>
void Base<D>::some_base_member()
{
  D d;
};
```

In fact, an important result of this pattern is that you can call a `Derived` member from the `Base` class. For example:

```
template <class D>
void Base<D>::some_base_member()
{
  static_cast<D*>(this)->some_derived_member();
};
```

Comment: A crucial piece of _CRTP_ is `static_cast< Derived* >( this )`

Comment: @K-ballo Thanks! I was just adding that.

Comment: Of course doing that in the constructor of `Base` would be _Undefined Behavior_, as `Derived` does not exist until its constructor finishes.

Comment: What you are showing is static polymorphism. I have no idea if this is what OP actually wants given how vague the question is.

Comment: Forgetting accessing via static cast (which I agree with), the one thing you should NOT do in the Base constructor is *instance* an object of type Derived (middle code snippet). Doing so recuses the "curiously recurring" into "blatant-recursion", which will eventually stack-fault.

Comment: Sorry, that is not what I was looking for.  I need to be able to have different derived classes at run-time, not just at compile-time.  Hopefully the edit I made to the question will help.

Answer (score 0):

You ask:

> “is it possible for the base class, in its constructor, to actually construct a member of the derived class (which then "pretends" to be a member of the base class, so nothing breaks)?”

Yes, there are many ways to do derived class specific initialization in a base class.

Here's one example from a blog posting that I wrote about it, entitled [“How to avoid post-construction by using Parts Factories”](http://alfps.wordpress.com/2010/05/12/how-to-avoid-post-construction-by-using-parts-factories/):

```
#include <stdio.h>

namespace apiLevel {
    enum Handle {};

    Handle newButton( char const title[] )
    {
        printf( "apiLevel::newButton(\"%s\")\n", title );
        return Handle();
    }

    Handle newListbox( char const [] = "" )  { return Handle(); }
    Handle newStatic( char const [] = "" )   { return Handle(); }
}  // namespace apiLevel

class Widget
{
private:
    apiLevel::Handle    handle_;

protected:
    struct ApiWidgetFactory
    {
        virtual apiLevel::Handle newWidget( char const title[] ) const
        {
            return apiLevel::newStatic( title );  // Reasonable.
        }
    };

public:
    explicit Widget(
        char const                  title[] = "\"? (unspecified)\"",
        ApiWidgetFactory const&     factory = ApiWidgetFactory()
        )
        : handle_( factory.newWidget( title ) )
    {}
};

class Button
    : public Widget
{
protected:
    struct ApiWidgetFactory: Widget::ApiWidgetFactory
    {
        virtual apiLevel::Handle newWidget( char const title[] ) const
        {
            return apiLevel::newButton( title );    // Derived class specific.
        }
    };

public:
    explicit Button(
        char const                  title[],
        ApiWidgetFactory const&     factory = ApiWidgetFactory()
        )
        : Widget( title, factory )
    {}
};

int main()
{
    Button  button( "Just a button" );
}
```

The main advantage of the above approach is that it presents a **type safe** interface to the client code, with ordinary RAII-oriented construction (i.e., makes good use of class invariants).

The main disadvantage is that it requires maintaining two parallel class hierarchies, even though that is mainly a question of where to put the code.

For more info see that blog posting, which also links further to [the FAQ](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/calling-virtuals-from-ctor-idiom.html), which also presents a few other approaches. The blog posting is sort of straight from the horse's mouth, namely mine. The FAQ item is the result of me convincing Marshall to write up that issue & solution for the FAQ.

Comment: I do not think that is what I am looking for.  Please correct me if I am wrong, but it seems to be functionally the same as the external function solution that I mentioned (see my edit if I did not explain myself well the first time).

Comment: @bugmenot: The function you showed, a simple factory function, is very different. Tthere is ordinarily *no need* for such a function, since it doesn't add anything (e.g. if you want to prevent non-dynamic allocation, simply make the destructor protected). The pattern above supports multiple derived classes such as `Button` and `Listbox`, with the common derived-specific data, here a handle to the API-level widget, initialized by the base class constructor.

Comment: I know that it would be useless for just one derived class, but I would actually be using multiple, and the constructor (or factory function) would choose between them based on its parameters.  Could you explain how yours is different?

Comment: @bugmenot: the function you showed, when amended to take a result-type indication argument, would still simply be a factory function. instead of calling the function to produce a `D` instance, you can just say `new D()`, which is also more clear and efficient! so apparently it serves no purpose. there is, apparently, no derived class specific initialization in the base class, for that function. the scheme above does derived class specific initialization, with a common concrete example where this is usually done. i suggest that you **study** that code. try it out, add a `Listbox` class. so on.

Comment: I see what you mean.  However, that is still not what I am looking for.  Essentially, if I have several derived classes (say, D1, D2, and D3), I want a way to get an instance of one of them, determined at run-time, based on other parameters.  For instance, given an integer value of 1, 2, or 3, it would return an instance of D1, D2, or D3, respectively, all cast to a B.  I do not need to do anything in the base class specific to which derived class was chosen; the base class is simply an abstract class to unify all of the derived classes.

Comment: @bugmenot: okay, that is indeed a factory function. and that's a very different question! it does *not* involve "for the base class, in its constructor, to actually construct a member of the derived class".